# Jython type of variable

Tags: python, jython-2.5

I'm creating a small script to fetch heap memory usage from java-application server. I was able to connect and fetch the data well. However when I try to tidy the output a bit with re-library I get TypeError which confuses me.

```
TypeError: expected str or unicode but got <type 'javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport'>
```

My regex:

```
re.search(r'\=(.*)$', result)
```

I tested type of output:

```
type(result)
```

Which yields following:

```
<type 'javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport'>
```

Is there anyway I can convert the output to string? str(result) did not work.

Comment: Have you tried `repr(result)`?

Comment: try replace `str(result)` to `result.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem here:

```
type 'javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport'
```

`result` must be `str`. You can get string representation of `CompositeDataSupport`. It may be `result.toString()` or other method from [here](http://edelstein.pebbles.cs.cmu.edu/jadeite/main.php?api=java6&state=class&package=javax.management.openmbean&class=CompositeDataSupport). Make some experiments with `CompositeDataSupport` methods.

**UPD** Note `toString` can return wrong result for your regexp if class author not overrided it from Object.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. Thanks for pointing me into right direction.